# pass the class method as pthread start function

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

Considering the following class

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        void* func(void* arg)
        {
            // how to pass this function to pthread...?!
        }
}
```

Later I want to pass `func()` to `pthread_create()`, instead of a function:

```
int main()
{
    char * msg = "Hi dude";
    Foo * ins = new Foo();
    pthread_t pt;
    // how to pass ins->func instead of a function?
    pthread_create( &pt, NULL, ins->func, (void*)msg );
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would the value of `this` be inside `func` when the thread invokes it?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: `ins`, obviously. ;-)

Comment: It's "thanks in advance", not "thanks in advanced"

Comment: What is your main purpose of trying to do so? If you want just to send some class internal data to thread, try to use last param

Comment: How would `ins` be passed to `func` to serve as `this`?

Comment: `char * msg = "Hi dude"` Nope...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'usual' approach is, to pack the object and all function arguments into a struct, allocate this struct on the heap, pass an instance of this struct to a function with C binding and let that function call the objects member function:

```
struct wrap {
    char * msg;
    Foo ins; 

    wrap( char* m, const Foo& f ) : msg(m), ins(f) {}
};

extern "C" void* call_func( void *f )
{
    std::auto_ptr< wrap > w( static_cast< wrap* >( f ) );
    w->ins.func(w->msg);

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    wrap* w = new wrap( "Hi dude", Foo() );
    pthread_t pt;

    pthread_create( &pt, NULL, call_func, w );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It does not work the way you tried **because** C++ member functions get the `this`-pointer of the object passed as their first argument. This is *implicitly* done by the compiler *if in C++ mode*.

However, `pthread_create()` is a **C** function. Its third parameter is "pointer to a function that takes a `void *` as argument (and returns `void *`)". Once inside `pthread_create()`, there is no `this`, there is no information that `this` should implicitly be passed as first argument... and the member function gets called in a very different way than it is intended to be called -- you are in all kinds of trouble.

That is why `pthread_create()` only works on functions that use "C" linkage: Global functions and static member functions (neither of which use a `this` pointer).

Torsten has a nice method of working your way around this limitation. I just wanted to elaborate a bit on the technical background of the problem.

Comment: Thanks dear, many thanks.as you mentioned about the pthread is c style and I'm using it in cpp app, but I stiill prefer it over cpp11 threading mode.

Comment: @parsaporahmad: Neither C++11 nor Boost threading allows you to call the member function of a generic class as "starting point" of a thread; actually they require you to work with special "thread" classes. Effectively, they face the very same problem (C++ calling conventions) as `pthread_create()`. They just provide a more C++-ish wrapper around the multithreading capabilities of the host OS (which are most likely based in C linkage).

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to declare the function as static

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
class Foo {
  public:
    static void* func(void* arg) {
      char *test = (char *) arg;
      std::cout << test << std::endl;
    }
};
int main() {
  char * msg = "Hi dude";
  Foo ins;
  pthread_t pt;
  pthread_create( &pt, NULL, ins.func, (void*)msg );
  pthread_join(pt, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```